# Unable to communicate between actors in Akka.Cluster

Tags: c#, akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I am having some problems in communicating between actors in Cluster.

My test project has this structure below.

**TestJob [C# Console Project]**

- TestJobService.cs
- TestJobActor

**MainProject [C# Console Project]** //Note: I configured this service as a seed node. I didn't use lighthouse.

- MainService
- JobManagerActor

Note: I don't want to put actors in Shared project or Main project. The actors that are supposed to do a test job should be under "TestJob" project.

I already followed this article http://getakka.net/docs/clustering/cluster-overview and video. I did enable Akka.Cluster based on the article. I am able to run both  console projects but when I tried to "tell" from JobManagerActor to TestJobActor, it doesn't work. No error but doesn't work.

I have this config in MainProject.

```
         actor {
               provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
               deployment {
            /TestJobAActor {
            router = consistent-hashing-group
                            routees.paths = ["/user/TestJobAActor"]
                    virtual-nodes-factor = 8
            cluster {
                   enabled = on
                   max-nr-of-instances-per-node = 2
                   allow-local-routees = off
                   use-role = backend
            }
            }                           
                 }
         }
```

Here is the code that I use for sending the message.

```
           var backendRouter = Context.ActorOf(Props.Empty.WithRouter(new ClusterRouterGroup(new ConsistentHashingGroup("/user/TestJobAActor"),new ClusterRouterGroupSettings(10, false, "backend", ImmutableHashSet.Create("/user/TestJobAActor")))));
            backendRouter.Tell("Yo yo!");
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Note: My test project with similar structure can be found here https://github.com/michaelsync/APMDemo . (VS2015 project)

One more question: Can we still use the actor selection when using cluster?

```
            var actorSelection = Context.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://MyBackendProcessingSystem@127.0.0.1:2553/user/BackEndJobAActor"); //This can come from Model
            actorSelection.Tell("Yo yo!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries!

I managed to fix it myself. You can see the fixes in my temp repo https://github.com/michaelsync/APMDemo/tree/allinoneproject.

1. The problem was that I didn't know I need to use IConsistentHashable for sending message in consistent-route. I keep on sending the string and didn't work.
2. local route was off.